# Qt5 on OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, qt, sdk

I installed XCode 4.2 and Qt 5.3 at OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).
When I trying to compile any project I got "Project ERROR: could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'".

Can I change sdk version to macosx10.6 at *.pro file or something?

Comment: Apologies for asking, but how did you get Qt 5.3 to install on 10.6? I tried earlier today, and found that the binaries contained references to newer ABIs... meaning even the install failed

Comment: I build it from sources.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I'm trying to do too, but I cannot seem to get it to build. Could you please post a description of how you proceeded? Do you have MacPorts installed (or Fink, or anything similar that might confuse the build system)?

Comment: Pure 10.6 Installation + MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.8

Then I used this guide:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx-building.html

Compillation was very long (several hours). I recommend skip webkit and examples compilation (see readme files in source folder).

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try once more then after hiding the MacPorts installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change sdk version to macosx10.6 at *.pro file or something?

This one

```
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.6
```

works well.

Answer (score 12):

I am working on Maverick, Xcode 6, Qt 5.3.2 & QtCreator 3.2.1:

1. On .bash_profile (one line):

   export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
2. On *.pro:

   QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9
3. Clean & qmake & build
4. DONE :)

Comment: Robert thank you for instruction! :) Have you got your debugger working? I can't start debugging.

Comment: Thanks but I asked about 10.6 (Snow Leopard) not about 10.9 :)

Comment: Alprog, this workaround works for 10.x :)
-Replace 10.9 to 10.6
-Replace SDKROOT to corresponding SDK path inside Xcode.

Comment: Does the .pro file accept a field to specify the installation location or directory of Qt? (I've got 4.8.6 installed as standard, but 5.3.2 in /usr/local)

Comment: Nevermind, the other answer by @maythe4thbewithu deals with this as there are three places to update.  The .bash_profile, the .pro file in the package and the qdevice.pri file in the installation of Qt5.  So yes, it looks like both Digia and Riverbank hard coded the use of OS X 10.8 in the current releases.  There are words to describe such configuration, but none of them are flattering.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may try

1) Open with a text editor

Qt5.3 /5.3 /clang_64 /mkspecs /qdevice.pri

2) change

!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.8

to

!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9

3) restart your Qt

Comment: Thanks but I asked about 10.6 (Snow Leopard) not about 10.9 :)

Comment: How about !host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.6. Don't work?

Comment: I expects this will let you don't need to set QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.6 in every .pro. But I have no Mac OSX 10.6 to try.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Updating qdevice.pri for 10.9 needs both lines changed to:!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9
GCC_MACHINE_DUMP = x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

Comment: Alprog, the 10.6 settings will be found by checking uname -a

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, but when building from sources there is a way to use the `./configure` script to set the sdk for you without having to fix it after the fact.

In your terminal with the sources and `configure` file in it, run the following command:

```
./configure -no-c++11 -sdk macosx10.6 -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license
```